# Powerhsell - Need to resolve IPs

Tags: json, powershell, dns, ip, fqdn

I can export the file containing the original data as either a json, xml, or csv. I chose JSON.

The JSON output looks like the below.

```
{
"entry":[{
"@name":"31.170.162.203",
"ip-netmask":
"31.170.162.203",
"description":
"test1"}
,
{
"@name":"37.193.217.222",
"ip-netmask":
"37.193.217.222",
"description":
"test2"}
,
{
"@name":"46.17.63.169",
"ip-netmask":
"46.17.63.169",
"description":
"test3"}
,
]
}
```

```
$input = Get-Content 'C:\Users\e\Desktop' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$iplist = $input.entry.'ip-netmask'


foreach ($ip in $iplist)   #for each line in the file...

{
    $hostnames = $null

    try {

        $hostnames = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("$ip").Hostname   #...resolve the ip

    }
     catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {

          $hostnames = "Server IP cannot resolve."
    }

    catch {

        $hostnames = "unknown error."

    }

    if ($hostnames -ne "Server IP cannot resolve.") {

        $ip -replace $ip, $hostnames

    } else {

        Write-Host $ip
    }
}
```

output:

```
31.170.165.68
31.170.162.203
l37-193-217-222.novotelecom.ru
```

This tells me it is replacing the resolved IPs, and keeping any original IPs that weren't resolved. This is exactly what I want

I ended up figuring out how to resolve them through further research, trial, and error.

Comment: Do the DNS names have reverse lookup records configured? If you do a `ping -a <ip>` or `nslookup <ip>` will you find the name there?

Comment: Yes some of them do

Comment: would you choose CSV and show the output it will be easier and to be clear you want to add the name of resolved instead of the IP or what would you clarify

Answer (score 1):

Thing 1- 
The posted json is not properly formatted.

Thing 2 -

Read in the json string, csv, xml file data and pass the IPA to the .Net class or DNS cmdlets to resolve them

One Example (as there are other ways)...

```
(@'
{
"entry":[{
"@name":"31.170.162.203",
"ip-netmask":"31.170.162.203",
"description":"test1"}
,
{
"@name":"37.193.217.222",
"ip-netmask":"37.193.217.222",
"description":"test2"}
,
{
"@name":"46.17.63.169",
"ip-netmask":"46.17.63.169",
"description":"test3"}
]
}
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty entry).'ip-netmask' | 
ForEach {
    $PSItem
    [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("$PSItem").HostName
}

#Results
...
37.193.217.222
l37-193-217-222.novotelecom.ru
...
```

or this way

```
(@'
{
"entry":[{
"@name":"31.170.162.203",
"ip-netmask":"31.170.162.203",
"description":"test1"}
,
{
"@name":"37.193.217.222",
"ip-netmask":"37.193.217.222",
"description":"test2"}
,
{
"@name":"46.17.63.169",
"ip-netmask":"46.17.63.169",
"description":"test3"}
]
}
'@ | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty entry) | 
ForEach {
    $PSItem.'@name'
    $PSItem.'ip-netmask'
    $PSItem.'description'
    [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("$($PSItem.'ip-netmask')").HostName
}


# Results
...
37.193.217.222
37.193.217.222
test2
l37-193-217-222.novotelecom.ru
...
```

Comment: Still not working. Using my original json file input i get:

Exception calling "GetHostEntry" with "1" argument(s): "The size of hostName is too long. It cannot be longer than 255 characters.
Parameter name: hostName"